# Is Champernowne's constant Liouville?

Tags: real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

By looking at extreme spikes of Champernowne's constant and how well it's approximated by some rational numbers I think it's reasonable to think that this is a Liouville number. However, no source I could find answered the question. Is the answer known?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The irrationality measure of the base $10$ [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant#Irrationality_measure) is $10$ (and similarly for other bases is the base).

The irrationality measure of [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) is infinite.

So a Champernowne constant is not a Liouville number.